# Filter a table based on max categorical occurrences

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have three columns table as below

```
| Category  | Author      | Sales     |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| NW        | account-1   | 10        |
| NW        | account-2   | 20        |
| NW        | account-3   | 30        |
| S         | account-4   | 10        |
| S         | account-5   | 50        |
| S         | account-6   | 55        |
```

I would like to produce another table with the maximum value of each category, the desired table should look like this.

```
| Category  | Author      | Sales     |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| NW        | account-3   | 30        |
| S         | account-6   | 55        |
```

My coding trial,

```
SELECT Category, Author, MAX(Sales)
FROM table
GROUP BY Category, Author
```

I'm not sure why `MAX()` aggregation fails (code above). Would appreciate if somebody to explain why in details & provide a simple and efficient solution.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your question **you need a sub-query**.

Explanation: Your **current solution does not work, because you *do not filter* the original query on max(Sales)**, but just ask "what is max sales for this category?". Therefore, you need another subquery, that

1. finds out the max of sales per category, so
2. you can then filter your original table on the combination of author and category that has an identical sales number as your max per category.

**The following code should work:**

```
SELECT tbl_sales.Category, tbl_sales.Author, tbl_sales.Sales
FROM tbl_sales
JOIN(
    SELECT Category, MAX(Sales) MaxSales
    FROM tbl_sales
    GROUP BY Category
    ) tbl_maxsales
ON tbl_sales.Sales = tbl_maxsales.MaxSales
```

You can find [a SQL fiddle implementation here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/857703/9).
(I assumed MySQL 5.6, but this should not play a big role)

If you have any questions or need more guidance please do not hesitate to shoot me a message or leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a correlated subquery for this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.sales = (select max(t2.sales) from t t2 where t2.category = t.category);
```

In particular, almost any database will take advantage of an index on `(category, sales)` -- if available -- to optimize this query.

The problem with your query is that you are aggregating by both `category` and `author`.  You want the maximum sales in `category`.  And you want the author *with the maximum sales*.  This is different from `max(author)` or from aggregating by `author`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Group by` is a group meaning, when you use `GROUP BY Category, Author` means you need to `group by` by `Category` and `Author` column, so there are six group.

**Query**:

```
select Category,Author
from t
group by Category,Author
```

**Results**:

```
| Category |    Author |
|----------|-----------|
|       NW | account-1 |
|       NW | account-2 |
|       NW | account-3 |
|        S | account-4 |
|        S | account-5 |
|        S | account-6 |
```

but If we only do `group by Category`, there are two groups.

**Query**:

```
select Category
from t
group by Category
```

**[Results]**:

```
| Category |
|----------|
|       NW |
|        S |
```

So you can try to get the `MAX` Sales column `group by Category` then join or connection with Sales and `Category`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    Category varchar(5),
    Author varchar(50),
    Sales int
);


insert into t values ('NW','account-1', 10);
insert into t values ('NW','account-2', 20);
insert into t values ('NW','account-3', 30);
insert into t values ('S','account-4', 10);
insert into t values ('S','account-5', 50);
insert into t values ('S','account-6', 55);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t t1 where exists(
  SELECT 1
  FROM T tt
  WHERE t1.Category = tt.Category
  GROUP BY tt.Category
  HAVING MAX(tt.Sales) = t1.Sales
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1fc16/5/0)**:

```
| Category |    Author | Sales |
|----------|-----------|-------|
|       NW | account-3 |    30 |
|        S | account-6 |    55 |
```

Answer (score 0):

max() don't  fail .. you are grouping by  Category, Author  so yoru query return each max sale for each combination between category and author in your table  .. 
..  if you need  the row related  to teh category with max sales you could use a  inner join on max result  subquery

```
  select * from my_table m
  inner join (

  select category, max(sales) max_sales
  from  my_table  
  group by category 



  ) t  on t.category  =  m.category and t.max_sales = m.sales
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try With Below Statement

```
SELECT * from TableName AS T1 WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM TableName AS T2
  WHERE T1.Category = T2.Category
  GROUP BY T2.Category
  HAVING MAX(T2.Sales) = T1.Sales)
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query to get your data

```
;WITH query AS (
    SELECT          
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  Category  ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS [Index],
        Category,
        Sales 
    FROM 
        table
)

SELECT * FROM query WHERE [Index] = 1
```